# La conjugaison du verbe asseoir

Tags: verbes, conjugaison

Je me demande pourquoi le verbe asseoir a deux conjugaisons et laquelle est la plus préférable.

En outre, selon la réforme de l'orthographe de 1990 il faut l'écrire assoir. Cependant je crois que cette forme reste toujours rare. Peut-on l'employer ? Est-ce connue ?

Comment: Tout dépend de votre auditoire. De vos lecteurs. Si vous vous adressez à ceux qui ont appris à lire avant 1990, *assoir* leur piquera les yeux. Sinon... ce sera l'inverse... http://chasseautresor-ng.0707a.net/forum/index.php?topic=82.0

Comment: Au vu des remarque et réponse, je pense qu'il serait bon de clarifier la question. En effet si je ne me trompe l'intention de départ était de savoir pourquoi on peut dire "je m'assieds"  ou "je m'ass(e)ois", pas de discuter sur la nouvelle vs ancienne orthographe avec ou sans "e"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Les formes variées d'assoir sont dues à plusieurs modèles concurrents, issus soit directement du latin, soit de l'analogie avec certaines formes conjuguées, et dont aucune n'a jamais véritablement pris le dessus.

**Les formes en /jɛ/**

La conjugaison originelle du verbe *assoir* est celle avec la racine courte en /asjɛ/ ou /asje/ et la racine longue en /asɛj/, qui sont les descendants attendus du verbe en latin vulgaire *assedēre*. (En syllabe accentuée, la voyelle longue ē donne /wa/ en français, tandis que la voyelle courte e donne /jɛ/ ou /je/)

> Je m'assieds < m'assié (A.Fr.) < me as**se**deō (la syllable accentuée en gras)

Pour la racine longue, elle est formée à partir du même e court quand il ne tombe pas sous l'accent et est suivi d'un suffixe accentué:

> Vous vous asseyez < vos asseez (A.Fr.) < vōs asse**da**tis (Latin vulgaire de Gaule)

Le yod de transition apparaît en moyen français par analogie avec le subjonctif:

> Que vous vous asseyiez < vos asseiiez < vōs asse**dia**tis (Lat. vulg.) < vōs assede**ā**tis (Lat. clas.)

Et se répand par analogie à la troisième personne du pluriel de l'indicatif présent, qui jusque là était *s'assiéent*.

On retrouve ces racines /asjɛ/ et /asɛj/ à l'indicatif présent et imparfait, ainsi qu'au subjonctif présent (et le futur et le conditionnel, sur lesquels je reviendrai). Les autres formes du verbe présentent d'autre racines, qui vont former la base des autres variantes de conjugaison d'assoir.

**Les formes en /wa/**

Elles proviennent toutes de l'infinif *ass(e)oir*, qui descend de manière régulière du latin vulgaire *assedēre*, avec *dē* comme syllabe accentuée.

Cet infinitif est similaire à celui de verbes comme voir et échoir, qui présentent une racine courte en /wa/ et une racine longue en /waj/. Par analogie, et depuis le XVIème siècle, certains locuteurs ont reconstruit la conjugaison d'*assoir* sur ce modèle:

> Je m'assieds > Je m'assois (cf. je vois)
>
> Vous vous asseyez > Vous vous assoyez (cf. vous voyez)
>
> Que vous vous asseyiez > Que vous vous assoyiez (cf. que vous voyiez)
>
> Je m'asseyais > Je m'assoyais (cf. je voyais)

À noter qu'il est courant en France de remplacer la racine courte /asjɛ/ par /aswa/, mais de conserver la racine longue /asɛj/: donc, "je m'assois", mais "vous vous asseyez".

**Les formes en /i(s)/**

Le passé simple et le subjonctif imparfait d'*assoir* forment la base d'un troisième paradigme.

En effet, ces formes sont similaire à celles des verbes du deuxième groupe:

> Je m'assis - Je m'enrichis
>
> Que je m'assisse - Que je m'enrichisse

Cette similarité a mené certains locuteurs à complètement reconstruire le verbe irrégulier du troisième groupe **assoir** en un verbe régulier du deuxième groupe: *assir*:

> Je m'assieds > Je m'assis (cf. je m'enrichis)
>
> Vous vous asseyez > Vous vous assissez (cf. vous vous enrichissez)
>
> Que vous vous asseyiez > Que vous vous assissiez (cf. que vous vous enrichissiez)
>
> Je m'asseyais > Je m'assissais (cf. je m'enrichissais)

Fréquent en français classique et dans les langues cousines du français, ce paradigme est aujourd'hui hautement stigmatisé, et surtout utilisé au Canada.

**Le futur et le conditionnel présent**

Ces temps peuvent se former sur la base des trois paradigmes décrits ci-dessus, mais le premier est dédoublé puisque et la racine courte /asjɛ/ et la racine longue /asɛj/ sont utilisées comme base de ces temps:

> Je m'assiérai (ʒəmasjeʀe)
>
> Je m'asseyerai (ʒəmasɛjʀe)
>
> Je m'assoirai (ʒəmaswaʀe)
>
> Je m'assirai (ʒəmasiʀe)

---

**Quelle paradigme utiliser ?**

Tout dépend d'où on se trouve.

Au Canada, ce sont les formes en /wa/ et en /i(s)/ qui dominent, mais vu le manque de prestige de cette deuxième forme, c'est le type "Je m'assois" qui est à conseiller

En Belgique, ce sont les formes en /jɛ/ qui dominent, les formes en /i(s)/ sont absentes et celles en /wa/, très typées français peuvent sembler trop précieuses. C'est le type "Je m'assieds" qui est à préconiser

En France,... En France, la question mériterait une étude sociolinguistique en profondeur, ainsi qu'une enquête des variations régionales. Il est clair que l'usage varie beaucoup selon les régions, mais que les formes en /wa/ et en /jɛ/ dominent, les premières étant perçues comme plus populaires et les secondes comme plus littéraires. Comme indiqué plus haut, des usages hybrides existent également.

Vu ces circonstances, difficile de conseiller une variante à préférer lorsqu'on interagit avec des locuteurs français, si ce n'est d'éviter *assir*.

Answer (score 1):

La réforme de 90 conseille des écritures qui s'embarassent moins de phonèmes datés pour uniformiser la langue écrite.
Les deux formes sont valables mais l'ancienne aura une connontation... ancienne, qui risque de provoquer des fautes de prononciation à l'oral et de complexifier inutilement les mots.
comme pour oignon/onion ou montaigne/montagne qui malgré les apparences sont censés se prononcer de façon identique, la réforme est là pour lever les doutes et correspondre aux usages qui ont évolué.

Comment: Non! L'ancienne n'aura pas de connotation ancienne. Cette réforme, bien que datant de 1990 n'est entrée dans les textes officiels que l'an passé et l'Académie note à son sujet dans la préface à la dernière édition de son dictionnaire que ce sera à l'avenir de juger laquelle des deux orthographes s'impose.